# Getting a sub-collection by a specific field value in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How do I find a subcollection based on a field value? I am currently using this code but it doesnt work:

```
var user = db()
    .collection('myCollection')
    .doc()
    .collection('private')
    .where("nam", "==", this.state.passcode);
```

What I am trying to achieve is making a custom authentication, so giving a custom username and password to users (in this case just a passcode). So I decided to store those credentials in a separate sub-collection inside a document. How can a user authenticate by comparing the values of username and password with the ones of a sub-collection?

Another question, is sub-collection for credentials a good idea? Will it cost the same to me as if I would store those info in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you're doing right now is not secure at all.  You should never store user credentials in a database, especially not one that's directly accessible to your web and mobile clients.  To do this properly, you should be making use of [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to sign in users.  (You tagged this question firebase-authentication, which refers to that product.)  In fact, doing security properly is very difficult.  Firebase Auth will make sure everything is done correctly.

Secondly, the query you have now will never yield any documents.  That's because you're not passing anything to `doc()`, which means it will return a DocumentReference to a non-existent document with a random ID.  If you meant to have some sort of unique identifier for each user, perhaps that's something you would want to pass to `doc()` so that each user's subcollection would be correctly identified.

Comment: Right now I am facing a strange problem, when querying a document, the code execution never reaches .then() callback. It doesnt throw any error, it just skips that part. I know the query is fine because I am testing with another one that worked before in another RN class.

Comment: You should always check for errors in a catch block.  If `then` isn't being triggered, then there is probably an error.

Comment: Nope, catch is not being called neither! It is really strange!

Comment: I will fix that later, but I have another question, what's the best way to implement a one code sign in, or at least without email? SO, instead of an email, I want the user to sign in with a username and password

Comment: Firebase Auth doesn't support that natively.  You would have to implement some custom auth if you wanted to integrate with Firebase.  The question is too broad to address on Stack Overflow if you're looking for suggestions.  You should probably start with some web searches.